# wp_query not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I've decided to start using `wp_query` instead of `query_posts`, on my home page I want to call the content from a particular page inside a div. Just wondering what am I missing here as nothing is appearing and I do have a page with content with an ID of 140. Im still quite new to this thanks!

```
<div class="home-info" > 
<?php 
if (have_posts() ) :

$the_query = new WP_Query( 'paged=140' );
while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
echo the_content();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

endif; 
?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the wrong argument in WP_Query, it should be `page_id` rather than `paged`.  Here's the reference from the Codex;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: Thank you McNab, I got it mixed up with the pagination argument. That worked perfectly! :)

Comment: No problem @Adrian glad to help - classic one where another set of eyes can spot it when you've been looking at it yourself for ages! :)